# How can I give a name to an IP address?

Tags: tomcat6

I am developing a web app using Tomcat. I want to give a name (a domain name) like "google" to access my site.

How can I do that?

Comment: I have a colloquially written tutorial on how to turn your home/office web server into an internet server. Depending on what you are looking for, you might find part of the answer there: http://g2h2web.blessedgeek.com/. However, I hope you are not attempting to learn to spoof google for phishing purposes, which would land you into a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 9):

If you only want to give a fake, temporal domain name for demo purposes on your development computer, you can add a line in your hosts file (typically located in /etc/hosts in UNIX/Linux systems):

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost

# My fake domain name for demo purposes
192.168.1.121   google.com
```

Then, when you open the 'google.com' domain name on your computer, it will redirect you to the specified IP address.

Note that this won't work if you want to access your application from other machines. You would have to make the same change in every computer's hosts file for that to happen.

And obviously, you won't be able to access the real google.com website while having that line in your hosts file.

For Windows systems, the only thing that changes is the location of the hosts file (you must be an Administrator to edit this file):

Windows XP/Vista/Windows7:

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Comment: How to do it in windows?

Comment: I added the path for Windows systems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read up on the [Domain Name System](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt) (DNS). The RFC is a bit dry so maybe start with [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

Once you understand the basics it's time to purchase a domain from a [registrar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar) and set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [register a domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registration), then set up [DNS records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) (including an `A` record that points the name to the IP address) on nameservers somewhere, and that IP address has to be accessible from the 'net. You may need [web hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting) for that, unless you have an always-on internet connection, in which case you need to configure your router to pass through port 80 traffic to the computer running the app.

There are many web hosting companies that will do the name registration and DNS setup and hosting for you if you host the site with them.

Answer (score -2):

1. You need some hosting to get your site on the internet
2. You need to register a domain name and point it at your hosting

Most hosting companies provide both services, which means you don't need to worry about "HOW" you do any of this.